# Update query with 1 int and 1 string

Tags: android, database

I have to update a row value form database using 2 values as conditions(1 integer value and 1 string).How can i write this..I wrote the following code..BUt it is showing error.Please rectify me.

```
long id=db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, initialValues, KEY_ROWID + "=" + update  and category ='Income' , null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nik..The above line itself showing some syntax error...I think the problem is with the checking condition...that is ("",') like that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is the where statement :

```
KEY_ROWID + "=" + update  and category ='Income'
```

It will be :

```
KEY_ROWID + "=" + update + "and category LIKE \"Income\""
```